# How can I deactivate registration if the user is logged in?

Tags: django, python-decorators, django-authentication, django-registration, django-login

I have got a website with a user registration and login. Both is working fine, but the registration page can still be accessed when the user is logged in. Maybe there is something like a @logout_required decorator I can wrap around the registration view?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. In your registration view, just add a simple `if` statement to check whether the user has logged in or not.

```py
def registration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #prevent user registration
        #...
```

you can use the same solution for CBVs (using `self.request.user.is_authenticated`).

or if you wish to do that in your template (for example, prevent the logged in user from viewing the registration form):

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you have a HTML file with a navbar on it to explain what needs to be done:

You can put this code in your template file in order to achieve this goal:

```
 <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Name</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li>
             <a href="/">logout</a>
         </li>

        {% else %}
            <li>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="/">Register</a>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the user_passes_test decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def not_logged_in(user):
  return not user.is_authenticated

@user_passes_test(not_logged_in)
def my_view(request):
  #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom decorator for that which will check if the request user is already logged in or not if yes then redirect to home.
Something like this.

```
def guest_user_only(view_func):
    def wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_view

@guest_user_only
def register(request):
    # your registration logic
```